# Regex Python: Extract words following a pattern from a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am new to pandas and need help with an regex expression. I want to extract all the words starting with AA and ending with AA in a column of  a dataframe.

I've used the following piece of code.

```
def getAA(text):
  text = str(text)
  result = re.findall(r'(AA).*?(AA)',text)
  return [result]

df['col']= df['col1'].apply(lambda x: getAA(x))
```

But I don't get the entire word , when i run it.

I'm expecting something like ['AAhelloAA','AAbyeAA']

I get the result as ['AA','AA'].

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: To get the text *between* two words, capture the `.*?` pattern, `re.findall(r'XX(.*?)XX',text)`. BTW, you may do it with the vectorized `Series.str.findall` method, `df['col']= df['col1'].str.findall(r'XX(.*?)XX')`

Comment: But now it just returns the text enclosed by AA, but i want the entire word

Comment: Then do not use a capturing group, `r'XX.*?XX'`

Comment: Yes I tried that. Thank You